# clGetMemObjectInfo return false result sometimes [OpenCL]

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl

I have a laptop with (**Intel i5 CPU** with **Intel HD 4000 GPU** integrated) and **NVIDIA GT653M** as discrete GPU.

I use the CPU as the host and the HD 4000 GPU as the device. both work on OpenCL 1.2

Q1: now when I am working with the `clGetMemObjectInfo` () function to obtain the host pointer(`CL_MEM_HOST_PTR`) of a memory buffer that wraps an array,  sometimes the function return the pointer correctly and sometimes it returns 0. my code is very simple, I want to know why is this occurs?

Q2: can I configure the CPU to be used as host and device at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- **khronos** specifies in OpenCL 1.2 `clCreateSubBuffer()` function documentation that

> The `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` and
>   `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` values cannot be specified in flags but are
>   inherited from the corresponding memory access qualifiers associated
>   with buffer.'

and this was not the case in OpenCL 1.0. so I modified it and it worked fine.

2- I did understand the architecture in a wrong way, so thanks.

Comment: Well, you didn't tell that you are using sub-buffers, it changes things. Anyway, it's great that problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that you've created your cl_mem's with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR allocation flag, otherwise your query for host pointer has no sense. Also, check return code of clGetMemObjectInfo() for specific error code.
2. Both CPU & GPU are OpenCL Devices, and can be used to build programms, run kernels, etc. So  yes, you can do this for shure.

Comment: @ 1- **khronos** specifies in OpenCL 1.2 'clCreateSubBuffer()' function documentation that _'The 'CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR', 'CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR' and CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR values cannot be specified in flags but are inherited from the corresponding memory access qualifiers associated with buffer.'_ and this was not the case in OpenCL 1.0. so I modified it and it worked fine. 

@ 2- I did understand the architecture in a wrong way , thanks.